# Broken image when trying to responde with content-type image/jpeg

Tags: html, node.js, image, express, routes

In my frontend html, I want an `img` tag with the source '/uploads/profilePicture'. When handling the request in node/express I want to authenticate the user, load the user's profile picture from the filesystem and respond with the image data. My code essentially boils down to this:

```
app.get('*', function(req, res, next) {
    /* Some code leading to the function getProfilePicture */
});

function getProfilePicture(req, res, next) {
    loadFile('uploads/' + req.user.local.picture, function(image) {
        res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'image/jpeg' });
        res.end(image);
    });
};
```

When the code is ran, the frontend shows a broken image, but no errors are printed in the console.

The interesting thing is that this has previously worked for me. A while ago my routing code was a lot less generic, because it used an `app.get()` for each page on my website. So I used `app.get('/uploads/profilePicture')` instead of `app.get('*')`. Could this be the problem?

**Edit:**

I'm using Node v0.10.35 and express 3.0.6.

**Edit 2:**

Tested with Express 3.19.1, still not working.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that using [res.sendfile](http://expressjs.com/3x/api.html) does the trick.

```
res.status(200).sendfile(URL);
```

Any explanation to why sendfile works but not setHeaders+end would be appreciated!